# Overlap Left Part Input using Styled Components in React

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I need to overlap the left part of the Input using styled-components in React. He will be able to write only after the overlap, on the right part.

Codesandbox is here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/overlap-left-side-input-styled-components-u81fi?file=/src/Input.js)

Just like this image below:

[image]

```
const TextInput = styled.input`
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #e3e5e5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what is to be done and where you are facing issue. Overlap not understanding

Comment: @Hitech Hitesh. How do you do something like the picture above, the left part, the one with the `testing name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would push the border styling and layout to the `Wrapper` component. Add a styled label component.

[image]

Code

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid #e3e5e5;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const InputLabel = styled.label`
  background-color: #e3e5e5;
  color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 28px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto; // <-- can set to specific width for consistency
`;

const TextInput = styled.input`
  border-width: 0;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
`;

const TextError = styled.span`
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ff0000;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 11px;
`;

const Input = ({
  label,
  name,
  type = "text",
  value = "",
  handleChange = () => {},
  error = null,
  touched = false
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <InputLabel htmlFor={name}>{label}</InputLabel>
        <TextInput
          id={name}
          name={name}
          type={type}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Wrapper>
      {error && touched && <TextError>{error}</TextError>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit overlap-left-side-input-styled-components (forked)]

Comment: Hi Drew. Could you make the input 's width100%? and also there a little white space around the  gray area. Could you fill it up also? Thanks

Comment: @Joseph The input should already be responsive and take 100% width from the `Wrapper` component, and as far as I can tell, the whitespace around the input is from the `body` element in the codesandbox, nothing in the input component. I added a CSS rule for the `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate same way as in the picture above. For the solution i added extra class to the *Wrapper*. Does this approach solve your problem? [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/overlap-left-side-input-styled-components-forked-lpibs?file=/src/Input.js:177-436)

```
const Overlap = styled.span`
  width: min-content;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 60px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  color: hsl(195, 2%, 68%);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
`;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you add the border radius and also put some padding on the text input. Make sure he can only type on white part. Right now, the text input is hiding on some part on the left